# What do you call food that is neither junk or healthy food?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> After that first encounter, Kazumi and Hidehiko started meeting
>   regularly at the McDonald’s. Once they got tired of junk food, they
>   switched to __ alternatives like curry rice, *soba* noodles, and
>   *miso* soup.

Is there a word or phrase for that? Not-so-unhealthy food?

Comment: They switched to to Japanese food.

Comment: The trouble here is that terms like 'junk food' or 'healthy food' are very subjective. Why can you not just say: "Once they got tired of junk food, they switched to alternatives like salmon sashimi, soba noodles, and miso soup."?

Comment: all food is healthy food - unless its junk food

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd reccomend using the comparative adjective **healthier**, as in *they switched to **healthier** alternatives*. It conveys that the foods they are switching to are not as junky as McDonalds but it doesn't have the connotation of *health food*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single word for this. Generally, English doesn't coin adjectives for things that are unexceptional in very particular ways (like being neither junk food nor salutary - it's just food at that point).

As one of the commenters noted, you don't actually need any adjective here - "alternatives" is already plenty. However if you really feel the need for an adjective, perhaps a phrase like "somewhat healthier" would satisfy.